# What are the different combos in Monster Blade?

Tags: monster-blade

On one loading screen the game informed me of the "Phoenix Talon" attack and gave the necessary steps to perform it (block, block, upward slash).

Through random slashing, I know I have hit other special moves.  The problem is I am never paying that much attention so I can never remember what I did to do other special moves.

On the [official website](http://nubee.com/2013/04/monster-blade-2/) it says:

> **Combos** –Combo moves are Special Moves that can be unlocked by various button combinations. All combos increase damage dealt compared to normal attack and add extra points to your battle score. Each Combo has different advantage and might be more effective on certain situation.

What are the special moves, how can I perform them, and what might be the advantageous situations for each?

Comment: Ever thought of looking in the game menu for combos? It would be a lot more effective than on here.

Comment: @Dupree3 Only combo I've seen has been mentioned in a loading screen.  Perhaps the others are there as well but I've not seen them.

Comment: Yes I understand that you have only seen them there, but have you looked for them in the menus? lol

Comment: @Dupree3 That was a fairly hidden menu, always thought of "settings" as more of a volume adjustment area.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem, I know they like to hide it a lot of times now. I don't own that game so I couldn't help you much more than that. Glad you found it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see combos by going to `OPTIONS -> SETTINGS -> Combos (tab)`.

[image: Monster Blade Combos Screen]

As far as when you would use each, I would guess it has to deal with some being multiple attacks.

**Note:** Information gathered from the Android App, version 1.3.3